# jQuery Mobile pageinit/pagecreate not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 5 pages - for ease lets say:

- one.html
- two.html
- three.html
- four.html
- five.html

When I load each individual page, both `pageinit` and `pagecreate` are firing correctly.

The Problem:

When I go from one.html to two.html, `pageinit` and `pagecreate` both fire, BUT when I go back to one.html (from two.html), `pageinit` and `pagecreate` DO NOT fire.

Why is this and how can I always fire `pageinit` and `pagecreate` on page load, as well as navigating through each page?

Update:

For each page I have:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-name">

 // content
</div>
```

To test the order at when things are firing I do:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','[data-role=page]', function(){
  console.log('PAGECREATE');
});
$(document).on('pageinit','[data-role=page]', function(){
  console.log('PAGEINIT');
});
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','[data-role=page]', function(){
  console.log('PAGEBEFORESHOW');
});
$(document).on('pageshow','[data-role=page]', function(){
  console.log('PAGESHOW');
});
```

How do I use the pagechange to always call the `pageinit` and `pagecreate`

Comment: onBack doesn't fire because your page is in DOM. Try disable ajax in jQuery mobile. Or if good, then rather then 5 different pages, try `data-role = page` for this. It works same as what you're looking for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're checking for the wrong events, pageinit and pageshow are what you should be concerned about.

**pageinit** fires everytime a page is loaded for the first time, jQM caches pages in the DOM/memory so when you navigate back from two.html to one.html, pageinit won't fire (it's already initialized)

**pageshow** fires everytime a page is shown, this is what you need to be looking for when you navigate back from two.html to one.html

Together you can pull off a lot of clean code, use pageinit for initializing, configuration etc and update your DOM to the initial state. If you have dynamic data on the page that may change between views, handle it in pageshow

Here's a good design for larger websites that we use in a production environment:

1. bind a live event to all pages/dialogs pageinit and pageshow events in some include that is on every page:

   `$(document).on('pageinit pageshow', 'div:jqmData(role="page"), div:jqmData(role="dialog")', function(event){`
2. I reference each page with a name: `<div data-role="page" data-mypage="employeelist">`
   In this live event you can basically have a switch statement for each page "name", and then check event.type for pageinit/pageshow or both and put your code there, then every time a page is created/shown this event will be fired, it knows what page triggered it and then calls the corresponding code
3. Now no matter what entry point a user lands on your site, all the handlers for all the pages are loaded. As you may already know, when you navigate to a page, it only pulls in `<script/>` within the div[data-role="page"] - ignoring any JS in the `<head/>`, placing separate JS on each page is a mess and should be avoided in any large site I believe
4. Try not to use blanket selectors in your jQuery, e.g. `$('div.myClass')` since this will search all of your DOM which may have more than one jQM page in it. Luckily in the live event handler for pageinit/pageshow mentioned above, `this` refers to the current page. So do all DOM searches within it, e.g. `$(this).find('div.myClass')` this ensures you are only grabbing elements within the current page. (of course this isn't a concern for ids). *Note in the pageshow event you can also use `$.mobile.activePage`, but this isn't available in the pageinit, so I don't use it for consistency*

I eventually had too much code, so I built a handler object where each page's js is included in a separate js file and can register handlers with the live event

The drawback is that all your js for your entire site is loaded on the first page the user reaches, but minified even a large site is smaller than jQuery or jQM so this shouldn't be a concern. *But if your site really is large I suppose you could look into RequireJS.*

An advantage is you are no longer loading all your JS for each page through AJAX each time the user navigates to a new page. **If all your JS is available on entry, you can now put debugger statements and debug much more easily!**

Comment: `pagecreate` can be used almost the same as `pageinit`. The difference is that `pagecreate` fires before widgets start to be initialized and `pageinit` fires after. The top of the documentation page about events has a big yellow block explaining this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html. Also note that if you want to do something for every time a pseudo-page is displayed you can just bind to the `pageshow` event because it fires  just after `pageinit` as well as for subsequent page-views.

Comment: but jquery said that pageinit is deprecated and should not be used!! https://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/ it says: ... Note: This event has been deprecated in 1.4.0 in favor of pagecreate. Simply replace pageinit in the above example.

Answer (score 3):

I believe `pageinit` and `pagecreate` are both only called once when the page is first initialized and created in the DOM, respectively.

You may want to look into the `pagechange` event http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 1):

You require a thourough read of the jQuery Mobile event documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

The above links gives some great insight into when each of the events fire, here are a couple samples from the page:

> **pageinit**
>
> Triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs.
>   We recommend binding to this event instead of DOM ready() because this
>   will work regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or if the
>   content is pulled into another page as part of the Ajax navigation
>   system.

.

> **pageshow**
>
> Triggered on the "toPage" after the transition animation has
>   completed. Callbacks for this event will recieve a data object as
>   their 2nd arg. This data object has the following properties on it:
>   prevPage (object) A jQuery collection object that contains the page
>   DOM element that we just transitioned away from. Note that this
>   collection is empty when the first page is transitioned in during
>   application startup.

To actually answer your question, don't use `pageinit`, use `pageshow`. `pageshow` fires on the initial showing of a page (just after the `pageinit` event is fired on the element) but also on subsequent visits to the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call some function each time before loading a page then you can use          pagebeforeshow i.e.

```
  $("#YourPageID").on('pagebeforeshow ', function() {
        //YourFunctionCall();
    });
```

as well as you can try binding your pageinit with page id but page init is called only     once while inserting your page in DOM. http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

```
  $("#YourPageID").on('pageinit', function() {
        //YourFunctionCall();
    });
```

Comment: Just a note, `.live()` has been depreciated, so be careful using it since it will probably disappear from jQuery Core at some point: http://api.jquery.com/live

Comment: +1 Thanks Jasper .on is replacement of .live(), i have tested .on() its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
$( document ).delegate("#pageid", "pageinit", function() {  
    console.log('PAGEINIT');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine

```
<div data-role="page" id="signupForm">
    ...
    ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</div>
```

test.js may contain the following code

```
// test.js starts here

$('#signupForm').on('pageinit', function(){
    // your code goes here
    ...
    ...

 });
// test.js ends here
```

In your login form, you may have link for signupForm and **data-ajax="false"** should be included in href tag that links to signupForm.

Happy Coding

Kuppuram

Answer (score 0):

If it is an ajax request to this page, the script should be written into body or else it doen't work at all for ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
..........
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" data-control-title="Detail" id="self_edit_page" data-theme="e">
...........
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
  $('#self_edit_page').bind("pagebeforeshow",function(event)
.......
  </script>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: need more explaination