# Added listview doesn't respond to click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a listview which I created with JavaScript/jQuery. When I click on a listitem I have to execute code.

**Scenario 1:**
I use this code:

```
$("div#home ul#one li").live('click', function() { console.log('click') });
```

this code picks up the click, but it picks it up twice. So when I click on a listitem it outputs two console.logs

**Scenario 2:**
I have this code for another list which was created in the normal index.html file.

```
$("div#home ul#two li").off('click').on('click', function() { console.log('click') });
```

This code doesn't execute the code twice.

Is there anyway I could get Scenario 2 working on the JavaScript created listview? (Any other suggestions are welcome too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not binding your `on` listener in the right place, you are declaring in a `pageinit` handler for **ANY** page to add your`on` listener to the li:`$("div#home").on('click','li', function() { console.log('click') });`

Thus you are attaching one listener on the `div#login` page and attaching a redundant 2nd listener on the second `div#home` page. When you click the `li` one event is fired to two listeners and you get the two clicks.

What you should be doing is in your `$(document).on('pageinit', function()` wrap your on listener declaration in a conditional that checks which page you're on:

```
if ($(this).attr(id') === 'home'){
     $("div#home").on('click','li', function() { console.log('click') });
}
```

That's the simple solution, what you really should be doing is branching your code based on which page fired the `pageinit` event and calling the correct code based on it. See: [my guide on structuring jQM Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538718/jquery-mobile-pageinit-pagecreate-not-firing/10542821#10542821).

The gist of it is attach a data attr to your `div[data-role=page]` etc that describes your page then call separate code for each page. *(instead of using the ID like in this example, because you can easily have more than one instance of a page in multi-page jQM apps)*

Answer (score 1):

If you are dynamically creating elements.. You need to use the delegated form

```
$("div#home").on('click','li', function() { console.log('click') });
```

Binding the event handler to the closest static parent that exists at the time of binding

If your `ul`'s aren't dynamic - you can bind it to the ul

```
$("div#home ul").on('click','li', function() { console.log('click') });
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I get the concept now :) But unfortunately, the code gives me two console.logs though

Comment: @AngeloA are you able to create a jsfiddle.net?  So we can troubleshoot it

Comment: check my post below, everything is included there

Answer (score 1):

To get scenario 2 working for dynamically appended element, use `on` with a delegate, like this:

```
$("#two").on('click', 'li', function() { console.log('click') });
```

I've shortened the first selector because if you're selecting by `id`, then it should be unique.

Also, I would assume the first scenario logs to the console twice because you have nested `li` elements?

Comment: there's no nested li inside, only a img, h3, p. But i'll try your code

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It gives me two console.logs

Comment: Can you please edit your OP to include the HTML structure you have. Thanks

Comment: check my post below, everything is included there

Answer (score 0):

I can't create a jsFiddle because this seems to can't load my function for a reason. I've put the script online on my own website.

http://anjirorijo.com/webapp/

The login settings are working. Just click login and there is the screen (home). If you click on one of the LI tags and open your console logs, you'll see 2 clicks instead of 1.

If there's any code you need, please comment below.

---

The current code which I use:

```
$("div#home").on('click','li', function() { console.log('click') });
```

can be found in the custom.js file

- sidenote: don't refresh the page when you're on the #home page. This will cause jQuery to not load the function which dynamically creates the list. Use logout and login again.

Comment: But this code isn't similar to my code. Your click li elements aren't dynamically created, mine are. That's where the problem starts

Comment: Yes.. I'm appending dynamic `li`'s on click.. then you can click the dynamic `li`'s and it still only clicks once

Comment: if anything.. try using event.stopPropagation

Comment: You're right. It does. Weird it doesn't work in my jQueryMobile app. Because it's the exact same code.

Comment: Fixed it! $("div#home").off('click').on('click','li',function() { }