# Where to put script tag inside jQuery mobile single page template

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, jquery-events

I have two page written in the single page template way.

Login.html has `<script src="login.js" />` in his `<head></head>` and this is like:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#loginPage", function(){
   $("#loginBtn").on("tap", function(){
      // if you are already authenticate or login success...
      $.mobile.changePage("Main.html");
   });
});
```

Main.html has is `<script src="main.js" />` in his `<div data-role="page" id="main"></div>` and this is like:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#main", function(){
//if not authenticated go to login
   $.mobile.changePage("Login.html");

    callJsonService();

$("#btnLogout").on("tap", function(){
            //do logout operatio and go back to login
    $.mobile.changePage("Login.html");
}).on("vmousedown", function(){
    $(this).addClass("tapped");
}).on("vmouseup", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("tapped");
});
```

If you navigate back and forward these 2 pages, every time you visited the page, the event bound with `on()` are fired two times, then three times, then four times etc. etc.

Why is this happening? It is due to the 'pageinit' event? or it is not correct to put the main.js inside the div with data-role=page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't load JS within your `<div data-role="page"/>` it will fire multiple times, I like to bind an `on` listener to the document root in a js file that I include on each page

```
$(document).on('pageinit pageshow', 'div:jqmData(role="page"),   
div:jqmData(role="dialog")', function(event){
```

Now place some sort of data variable or class on your `<div data-role="page" data-pageid="foo"/>` to distinguish between your different pages, now you have two variables to branch your code on

1. **event.type** = pageinit/pageshow: the first fires once only for each
   page, latter will fire on first load and re-fire if you press back
   and navigate back to the page
2. **$(this).data('pageid')** = whatever you want, in this case when page *foo* fires either event you can handle appropriately, no surprises

See my older answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10542821/737023 for more detail

Comment: Thank you for the resposne, i'm really interested into it.
But i can't understand clearly:
I have to put only 1 js file that bind pageinit and pageshow?
And in this file do i have to distinguish between pages?
And do i have to distinguish between pageinit and pageshow?
So where do i have to put the binding to the event like tap?

Comment: Yep, in the one file you can check if it's `pageinit/pageshow` by checking `event.type` which is passed in, and you can attach a data variable to the page for example: `<div data-role="page" data-pageid="myFirstPage">`now in the callback to that code above you have three main variables, `this` = the current page executing, that's where you add any bindings, you want to add the binding when the `event.type` is `pageinit` and when `.data('pageid') === 'myFirstPage'` because pageshow fires more than once and you only need to bind once.

Comment: You eventually want to have more than one JS file if you have more code, everything should just start from the `pageinit/pageshow` callback handler. You can definitely have other functions in other JS files you call.

Comment: since `this` in the callback handler refers to the calling page, you should also do `$(this).find(` for elements you want to interact with, this is because jQM "may" append multiple pages into a single DOM - if you did something like `$('.myHeaderClass')` you can inadvertently select elements in the inactive pages.

Comment: Ok it works by loading all the javascript in the main page, the one who is accessed by HTTP.

But i wonder if i have a lot of js files, can i use $.load(<filename.js>) to inject the script?
Because if i put it into the div with data-role="page" of the different pages, this causes the sum of the event handler, so if i tap once the vent is triggered several times (as many as i visit the page).

Comment: Yep definitely do that, or use requireJS, any dynamic script loading would improve performance - I just don't bother unless I have a really large site.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some inconsistencies here. Using the SPA templates and loading multiple physical pages results in the logical pages (contained within your `<div data-role="page"></div>` tags) being loaded via ajax and added to the DOM. By placing script tags within these logical pages, the script is firing multiple times (once for each page load) and resulting in your multiple event bindings.

You should place all of your script outside of the logical pages. A good place is within the header of your initial page (main.html).