# JQuery Mobile - ListView - Get the selected item

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, click

I have looked at other questions on this and so far I haven't been able to solve the issue that I've got:

HTML :

```
        <script type="text/html" id="searchPickPlaceTemplate">
                 <div class="searchpickwhere_box">
                     <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
                 </div>
         </script>
         <div id="searchPickPlace"></div>
```

I have created a jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/antaeusa/TLGY7/2/
Since I am dynamically adding items to the listview. I have also given each item an id to easily identify what item has been clicked, so that I can pass that value to another page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You had some errors in your javascript and html files.

In Jquery Mobile when defining a listview you must include `data-role="listview"` to the definition of a `ul`, that way jquerymobile will understand that you want a listview and not a "normal" list.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <!-- List Elements -->
</ul>
```

The second error you had was that there is no `data-name` attribute defined on the html, and you were trying to get it with javascript.

```
$('#searchPickPlace ul').children('li').bind('touchstart mousedown', function(e) {
    alert('Selected Name=' + $(this).attr('data-name'));
});
```

This obviously won't work if the selected element does not have defined that attribute.
So you must define it on the html, like this:

```
<div id="searchPickPlace">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-name="Remuera"><!-- List element content --></li>
        <li data-name="Posonby"><!-- List element content --></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

I modified your code and here is the full solution to your problem, hope it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/TLGY7/12/

**Note:** If you're going to dynamically add more elements to the listview you must call the `$('.selector').listview('refresh');` method on every element added. Here's the link to the docs:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-methods.html

Comment: I'm not sure what was the purpose of the binding a callback to the `#restWhere` element, but for me does not have a lot of sense binding to the `document` element the `pageshow` event everytime you click on the `#restWhere` element. If you do that, you'll end up with several `pageshows` events binded to the `document` element, adding one more callback every time the user clicks the `#restWhere` element. Please check this solution http://jsfiddle.net/fhbjJ/1/ also note the `$("#mylist").refresh("listview");` at the end of it. And make sure you check this basic book: http://jqfundamentals.com/

Comment: The pageshow, method was the way that I could show all the items via the ajax call, because I didn't know what event fires but found this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10542821/1238887. I'll take a look at that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I know i am too late for the answer but might be helpful to other developers.Even i found this link when i was looking for same query and finally i have found some grate and easy solution.

In here i have use with static array but same thing i have use with dynamic array so you can easily check that difference.

I have use custom list view and retrieving data from HTML 5 database (Phone Gap). So Mobile developer can write code as bellow,

```
function DB_QuerySuccess(tx, results) {
    console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
    var com_id_array = []; // init array     
    var com_name_array = []; // init array
    var com_img_array = []; // init array

    //this will return user_id if user exist else return "no user"
    if (!results.rowsAffected)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < results.rows.length; index++) 
        {
            var item = results.rows.item(index);
            var com_id = item.com_id; // company id
            var com_name = item.com_name; // company name
            var com_photo = item.com_photo; // company name
            com_id_array.push(com_id);
            com_name_array.push(com_name);
            com_img_array.push(com_photo);

              $('#ls_com_list').append('<li><img id="com_img" src="'+ com_img_array[index] +'" width="100px" height="100px"/><h3>'+com_name_array[index]+'</h3><p>'+com_id_array[index]+'</p><div align="right"><img src="img/add_icon.png" width="20px" height="20px"/><img src="img/icon-action-close.png" width="20px" height="20px" onclick=\'alert("i am at "+"'+ [index]+'"+" position")\'/></div></li>').listview('refresh');
        }
    }
```

}

So, when you click on Right side button Alert will pop up and show current index.

I think Web developer can also same thing.

I hope this will help you guys.

- [Live Demo : Custom List View](http://jsfiddle.net/Tkrnx/21/embedded/result/)
- [Get Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Tkrnx/20/)