# Listview refresh not working on dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, dynamic-loading

I've been trying for about 10 hours now with no avail to refresh my listview through jquery.
I'm dynamically loading a list and it wont refresh to obtain the styling..
What in the flying fudge am I doing wrong.

```
<div data-role="content" id="content">
    <ul id="dataList" data-role="listview" data-autodividers=true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." data-inset="true" >
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var $dataList = $("#dataList");
    $.getJSON( "starWars.json", (function( data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            $dataList.append('<li ><a href="#'+item.name+'" ><img src="images/'+item.pic+'" alt="'+item.name+'"/><h1>'+item.name+'</h1><p>'+item.about+'.</p></a></li> ');
        });
    }));
})();
</script>
```

Comment: it is just a matter of asynchronous events. You can't predict which event will occur first... You should get the JSON data inside the JQM page init event: `$(document).on("pageinit", "#pageId", function(){...` Then, You can refresh the JQM widget, because You know that it has been already instanciated. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45021128/4845566

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an plugin for your list view maybe you should refresh the the plugin too

Comment: Hi Arash not sure if I am or not, I'm using jquery and jquery mobile do either or these give an automatic plugin? It refreshes atomatically once I type something into the search bar. So I know the code is fine... Just the dreaded refresh..

Comment: Ok.i have not worked with jquery mobile but if it is like jquery use this: `$.ajax({  url: $url , type:'GET',success:function(r){ var res = JSON.parse(r); // write your each loop and append here }  });`